# Timer in beamer footline

Tags: beamer, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to add a timer to a Beamer presentation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/689/is-there-a-way-to-add-a-timer-to-a-beamer-presentation)

Is there a way to add a timer at the footline of a `beamer` presentation that will tell us how long the presentation has been going on?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/212683/using-cronominutes-with-antibes-theme

Answer (score 3):

Yes, by using the [`tdclock` package](http://pcmap.unizar.es/numerico/software.php), but this will require a Javascript-enabled viewer (and that means, AFAIK, Reader only). The package comes with an example Beamer presentation.