# Using `\cronominutes` with Antibes theme

Tags: beamer, macros

[This is a nice post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/689/is-there-a-way-to-add-a-timer-to-a-beamer-presentation) that discusses the use of the `\tdclock` package. Following the tex demo provided in its answer, I modified my MWE below to use a stopwatch with the macros `\cronominutes` of that package. The problem is that I use the Antibes theme and would like to ask for support to add that stopwatch in the left corner (contrary side of the page numbering) in each slide.

I appreciate your support to achieve this, thanks in advance,

MWE:

```
\documentclass[compress,final]{beamer}

\usetheme{Antibes}
    \setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
    \setbeamercovered{transparent=25}
    \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}

\usepackage{ragged2e}       % for justifying
\usepackage{lipsum}         % for random texts
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{lmargin=.5cm, rmargin=.5cm}
\usepackage[font=Times,timeinterval=60,timeduration=30.0,timewarningfirst=15,timewarningsecond=25,timedeath=0]{tdclock}

\begin{document}

    \quad\cronominutes                                      % for crono stopwatch

\section{ITEM}
\subsection{item}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \scriptsize\justifying
        \item \lipsum[2]
        \item \lipsum[1]
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a new template based on the `frame number` one for `footline`:

```
\documentclass[compress,final]{beamer}
\usepackage{ragged2e}       % for justifying
\usepackage{lipsum}         % for random texts
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{lmargin=.5cm, rmargin=.5cm}
\usepackage[font=Times,timeinterval=60,timeduration=30.0,timewarningfirst=15,timewarningsecond=25,timedeath=0]{tdclock}

\usetheme{Antibes}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}

\setbeamercovered{transparent=25}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\defbeamertemplate{footline}{crono frame number}
{
  \quad\cronominutes%
  \hfill%
  \usebeamercolor[fg]{page number in head/foot}%
  \usebeamerfont{page number in head/foot}%
  \insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber\kern1em\vskip2pt%
}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[crono frame number]

\begin{document}

  \initclock

  \section{ITEM}
  \subsection{item}
  \begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
      \scriptsize\justifying
      \item \lipsum[2]
      \item \lipsum[1]
    \end{itemize}
  \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The following shows the placement of the clock in bottom left. (It does not show the clock itself because, as is common, my PDF viewer does not support it.)

[image: clock bottom left]

Note that I think you should reconsider your layout here. Using `geometry` and justification to make it look more like a printed page is going to make things more difficult than necessary for your audience (unless, of course, you print your presentations rather than displaying them on a screen).

Comment: it works perfectly, thanks a lot for that. The only thing was to put the `\initclock` inside the frame environment, because there is one empty slide when `\initclock` is inmediately below the `begin{document}`. The thing with `geometry` and `justifying` is only for the MWE, but thanks also for the tip =)