# beamer : show time in real time

Tags: beamer

Is there any command that displays the time in beamer class in real time?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{
\usetheme{mytheme}   

\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[arabic]{babel}
\usepackage[french]{babel} 
\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}
```

Comment: related [Is there a way to add a timer to a Beamer presentation?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/689)

Comment: You mean the time you're employing during the presentation? Or the time you planned to use?

Comment: the first : the duration of the presentation

Comment: @cmhughes : i used tdclock package, it works very well when i put it in the centre of  page but id dosn't work at the place reserved to the date!!

Comment: @physics could you update with your question with what you've tried :)