# Is there any package like tdclock which can be used in SumatraPDF

Tags: beamer, datetime, sumatrapdf

I find some errors when using `\usepackage[timeinterval=1]{tdclock}`while opening the SumatraPDF.

As  zeniko says

> The tdclock package only works in PDF readers supporting JavaScript,
>   which SumatraPDF currently doesn't and likely never will.

so I want to find the package like tdclock which can be used in SumatraPDF

Ps: tdclock is used in beamer to show the clock.

Comment: There won't be.

Comment: You are looking in the wrong direction. No package can introduce Javascript into SumatraPDF. If you really need it, you have to use Acroread for a while.

Comment: @percusse So how about making time not using Javascript? I don't care about whether to use the Javascript. I only want to add the time in the beamer. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Your wish seems hardly possible. PDF is a static document which does not go very well along with displaying dynamic things like clocks.

However there are some possibilities:

- use a pdf viewer which is capable of javascript (acrobat reader beeing only one example) to use `tdclock`. For configuration of others viewers see for example [Foxit Reader](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/321075/beamer-pdf-presentation-viewer-to-play-embedded-videos-and-show-elapsed-time).
- let your pdf viewer display the clock. Some examples can be found at: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1019/36296, [Is there a nice solution to get a "presenter mode" for Latex presentations?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21777/is-there-a-nice-solution-to-get-a-presenter-mode-for-latex-presentations).

Comment: Could you give an example of another viewer which supports Javascript? Especially useful would be something which works on platforms where Acroread is not (or no longer) supported.

Comment: @crf Seems tdclock also works with Foxit Reader, but I did not test myself as I don't have windows:  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/321075/beamer-pdf-presentation-viewer-to-play-embedded-videos-and-show-elapsed-time