# Can I have another choice to add the time in beamer except the tdclock

Tags: beamer, datetime

Last time, I question that the sumatrapdf cannot show the time.
you can see
[sumatrapdf question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140559/is-there-any-package-like-tdclock-which-can-be-used-in-sumatrapdf)

And I get the answer it doesn't support the java.

Then I use the Adbreader,it's ok.

Now, Regardless of things whether Javascript or not, I only want to know  whether I can have another choice to add the time in beamer except the tdclock. Say thank you in advance  :)

Comment: have you seen this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/689/is-there-a-way-to-add-a-timer-to-a-beamer-presentation ?

Comment: @dcmst Thank you, that's helpful. I know what I can do.

Comment: Voted as a dupe, since there's really no material difference between this question and the user's previous question.