# Show clock in beamer presentation

Tags: beamer

Is there any possibility to add a `clock` to be shown in each slide using `beamer`?

Comment: What kind of clock? Just any clock? The current time? Should it tick on a current slide?

Comment: @Werner, I need to count the time of my presentation.

Comment: @phdstudent: Why not just use a stopwatch? The PDF file format is fixed, so if you want a dynamic counter to keep track of it, it has to use Java (supported by certain PDF viewers). Also, what good would a counter be for the viewer? Instead you can use a [`beamer` progress bar](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59742/5764). It's far more useful to the viewer that a clock.

Comment: take a look at: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/689/is-there-a-way-to-add-a-timer-to-a-beamer-presentation

Comment: There are also some nice visual counters [Visual counter for LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140619/13304)

Comment: would the 'tdclock' theme do what you want?http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tdclock

Comment: What about an always on top external clock application? Is that a total abomination? :) I think it IS the easiest and most elegant way...

Comment: You can use `impressive`. It has a clock with `t` shortcut. http://impressive.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @HarishKumar: why don't you transform your comment to an answer?

Comment: @SándorKazi Answer added :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a package called `tdclock`. However, to make it useable it must be patched. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/148464

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[font=Helv,timeinterval=60]{tdclock}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{\initclock\tiny{\tdyear-\tdmonth-\tdday\quad\tdhours:\tdminutes}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Frame title}
\dots
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

[impressive](http://impressive.sourceforge.net/) offers, among lot of other features, a clock that shows the time elapsed on the right upper corner. The clock is visible to audience also. The clock can be made visible/invisible by the short cut key  <kbd>t</kbd> . For details of other features and short cuts refer to the impressive documentation (impressive.html, found in the same folder).

Comment: Ok. That is cool! But how to use it? Could you give more details? The informations in the website are poor.